# I keep getting a runtime error 13 in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

The code below works fine at first, but if I delete all the data from the cells I get the error “error 13” and then the code stops working. Is there any way to resolve this issue? I have included the code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Target = StrConv(Target, vbProperCase)
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

If Target.Column = 3 Then
    Target = StrConv(Target, vbProperCase)
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

If Target.Column = 6 Then
    Target = StrConv(Target, vbProperCase)
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

If Target.Column = 7 Then
    Target = StrConv(Target, vbProperCase)
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to test for content in the cells and handle when there isn't. Your code simply cannot handle there being no content, and you need to fix that.

Comment: How would I do that? I am very new to coding.

Comment: Perhaps describing that purpose of this script will help narrow this down. What does this do?

Comment: The script is used to force proper case in different columns of a spreadsheet. Specifically columns A,C,F,G. I found the code online and it works fine even when I delete the data one cell at a time but if I select all data in a row and delete it then the formula stops working.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete one row your code errors at line `Target = StrConv(Target, vbProperCase)` (Col 1)

You are changing all cells in the row, so the Target contains multiple cells

- `StrConv()` only accepts one string
- Before the error you turn `Application.EnableEvents = False`
- After the error the code stops and doesn't get to execute `Application.EnableEvents = True`

so now all events are off

---

This version will check for those possibilities:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then            'one cell
            Select Case .Column
                Case 1, 3, 6, 7:
                    If Not IsError(.Value2) Then
                        If Len(.Value2) > 0 Then .Value2 = StrConv(.Value2, vbProperCase)
                    End If
            End Select
        Else
            Dim cel As Range, ur As Range
            For Each cel In Target         'multiple cells (copy/paste, del/insert rows/cols)
                With cel
                    Set ur = UsedRange
                    If .Row > ur.Rows.Count Or .Column > ur.Columns.Count Then Exit For
                    Select Case .Column
                        Case 1, 3, 6, 7:
                            If Not IsError(.Value2) Then
                                If Len(.Value2) > 0 Then
                                    .Value2 = StrConv(.Value2, vbProperCase)
                                End If
                            End If
                    End Select
                End With
            Next
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

This works fine in `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` also